# Change the display language of a file type in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

For certain file types the name of the file type is displayed in cyrillic while viewing a directory listing in Explorer. See below image for an example.

[image: Windows 10 File Explorer image showing different languages]

As you can see the file type in File Explorer doesn't display in English.
How can I change the language to English?

Comment: Adjust the necessary registry entries (probably a system wide change).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your Explorer. The version of Visual Studio you have downloaded and installed is probably in multiple languages i.e. English and Russian.

1. Open VS Installer from the start menu, click on the Languages tab uncheck Russian (make sure English is checked) then click *Update*.
2. Open VS, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, type *Language*. You will get some results. Then click Environment > International Settings (Change the environment language) and change it to English.

You may need to restart your system.